# Setting The Master Record in a Salesforce Merge Account URL Hack

Tags: account, urlhacking, merge

I am trying to build a hyperlink within excel that opens up the Salesforce merge page.

From my understanding of reading different forums we can hack the URL to bypass SFDC limitations.

The Merge Accounts page URL:

```
https://emea.salesforce.com/merge/accmergewizard.jsp
```

A parameter is then passed to indicate that SFDC should start merging, and it will expect account IDs to be on the URL:

```
goNext=+Next+
```

The last segment is a collection of SFDC Account IDs. All use the parameter name of "cid"

```
&cid=001j000000hdR0OAAU&cid=001j000000hdR5FAAU
```

Full url

```
https://emea.salesforce.com/merge/accmergewizard.jsp?goNext=+Next+&cid=001j000000hdR0OAAU&cid=001j000000hdR5FAAU
```

This URl Takes me to the following page.

[image: Account Merge]

As you can see the default master record is "mason 2", how can i make "Mason 1" the master record ?

I have switched  the position of the Id within the URL but still not able to get the Master account to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around, I established that we need to another criteria in. By adding &p2=001j000000hdR5F this will help choose the master record

https://emea.salesforce.com/merge/accmergewizard.jsp?goNext=+Next+
&p2=001j000000hdR5F
&cid=001j000000hdR0OAAU
&cid=001j000000hdR5FAAU